# Xaml Serialization

Tags: xaml

I want to use xaml serialization to store the configuration data of my application. This info is represented as readonly properties of a custom configuration class. When loading the application, the configuration class is deserialized through xamlservices api from a text file. However, I get an error in the form:
`Cannot set unknown member 'property_name'.' Line number '24' and line position '4'.`
This is because the setters are private. Is there a way to deserialize the object with readonly properties through xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you won't get round-trip serialization. You write a XAML document in which the object  you want is created using a non-default constructor.

Look up info about the  directive.

Answer (score 0):

If its a collection property you can try using the [ContentWrapperAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentwrapperattribute.aspx).
You can also look at the [ValueSerializerAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.valueserializerattribute.aspx)

More info can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff354959.aspx